# Leaflet fullscreen button not showing

Tags: typescript, leaflet

I am currently learning TypeScript by working on a small project.

I had an issue with Google free trial, so i switched to Leaflet.

My question is how to display the full screen button in the map, here are code samples.

in my CustomMap.ts:

```ts
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { User } from './User';
import { Company } from './Company';


//instructions to every other class
//on how they can be an argument to 'addMarker'
interface Mappable {
    location: {
        lat: number;
        lng: number;
    }
}

export class CustomMap {
    private leafletMap: L.Map;

    constructor(mapDiv: HTMLElement) {
        this.leafletMap = new L.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: [40.731253, -73.996139],
            zoom: 2,
            fullscreenControl: true,
            fullscreenControlOptions: {
                position: 'topleft'
            }
          })

          
        var layer = new L.TileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
                tileSize: 512,
                zoomOffset: -1
            }).addTo(this.leafletMap);
    }

    addMarker(mappable: Mappable): void {
        let marker = new L.Marker(
            L.latLng(mappable.location.lat, mappable.location.lng)
            )
        marker.addTo(this.leafletMap).bindPopup('').openPopup();
    }
}
```

In my index.ts:

```ts
import { User } from './User';
import { Company } from './Company';

import L from 'leaflet';
import { CustomMap } from './CustomMap'

const user = new User();

const company = new Company();

const customMap1 = new CustomMap(document.querySelector('#map'));


customMap1.addMarker(user)
customMap1.addMarker(company)
```

Here is index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="map" style="height:500px; width:500px;"></div>

    <script src="/src/index.ts">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically this code generates a map with the zoom in + zoom out button, but no fullscreen button (by the way I use parcel-bundler)

Comment: I look at your code and I see that you have not added the full screen plugin and styles related to it anywhere :)  [fullscreen](https://github.com/tomik23/leaflet-examples/blob/master/27.fullscreen/index.html#L11)

Comment: would u please tell me what code to add and where exactly

Comment: Line 11 and 12 in my code. You just miss the js and css library. Second thing `ts` is not an executable needs to be converted to js.
I recommend that you find a javascript basics course, for example on YouTube, start js basics and then start with typescript.

Comment: i have literally added the lines you told me to index.html file , but it doesn't work.
also i am not newbie to JS because i have already implemented a leaflet map with all features with vanilla js, with typescript i tried many solutions including the one u told u me to do but no result

Comment: You probably haven't read the end ;) You won't run `*.ts` files in your browser. You cannot use them this way `<script src="/src/index.ts"></script>` First you need to compile this `index.ts` file to js and add it to the website :)

Comment: "So basically this code generates a map with the zoom in + zoom out button, but no fullscreen button (by the way I use parcel-bundler)"
this is what i have said in my post i am already using parcel to compile the ts code

Comment: If you can, create an example on this page https://codesandbox.io/
There is an option to use `parcel` with typescript

Comment: here u go [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-map-fsy11)

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, take a look at [my solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-map-forked-clr83?file=/src/CustomMap.ts)
I used this plugin [leaflet.fullscreen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bepo65/leaflet.fullscreen)
unfortunately the official one has a lot of problems with typing and he didn't want to work with me ;) The problem is also with the display of the icon, but you have to solve it yourself ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the time u gave me and the help, i think the icon problem is easily solvable consider that the fullscreen feature is there now :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in Fullscreen button in Leaflet unfortunately.

You can add this feature with a plugin, see https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#fullscreen-controls

Comment: i was trying this whole morning to make it work, i mean using vanilla JS is quite easy to get it to work, but typescript makes it a little complicated. would u like to tell me what should i add to make this extention work, since i have posted the ts files here?

Comment: You have typings for some plugins, see e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet.fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

Not in typescript but see maybe this solution worked.
I am using this plugin [Leaflet.fullscreen](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.fullscreen)
Here I have a way to use [react-leaflet-examples](https://tomik23.github.io/react-leaflet-examples/)
and below all the code:

```js
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet-fullscreen/dist/Leaflet.fullscreen.js';
import 'leaflet-fullscreen/dist/leaflet.fullscreen.css';
import tileLayer from '../util/tileLayer';

const center = [52.22977, 21.01178];

const MapWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <MapContainer
      fullscreenControl={true}
      center={center}
      zoom={13}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}
    >

      <TileLayer {...tileLayer} />

    </MapContainer>
  )
}

export default MapWrapper;
```

Comment: Thank u very much for the tip, i was actually going to start  a react project that implements leaflet map so this code is very useful to me, as for the typescript part i will leave it as it is since i was just learning how to use leaflet :D

Comment: There is also a link to a plain js version without react [leaflet-examples](https://github.com/tomik23/leaflet-examples) 
It's best to create an example at https://codepen.io/